# Is there a way around whatever the iPad is doing with my site?

Tags: ipad, navigation, ios-simulator

I have recently taken up web design and I am in no way an expert. I am developing this site for myself and I seem to be having some problems. This site looks about the same (it's still under development) across all browsers and I've been working on tablet and mobile phone specific css. While doing testing for the iPad (I use the xCode iOS Sim) I noticed that my menu bar was not working except in what seem like random moments (usually when I was zoomed in). I had a family member test this on their physical iPad and they couldn't use the nav bar at all. This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cd3R8/) link contains the html and css that run the navbar. I will be spending the next few hours working on this and will update or remove this post if I figure it out, but if I do not, any help is appreciated.

This is the html only, the css is too long.

```
<h2><a href="/">Auburn PC Repair<br>& Building</a></h2>
<div id="header-image">
    <h1></h1>
</div>

<nav id="buttonbar">
    <ul>
        <li id="services-button"><div class="buttonHighlight"></div>
            <a href="#" class="button"><h3>Our Services</h3><p>how can we help you</p></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/services/pcrepair">PC Repair</a></li>
                <li><a href="/services/mobiledev">Mobile Device</a></li>
                <li><a href="/services/networking">Networking</a></li>
                <li><a href="/services/pcbuilding">PC Building</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="contact-button"><div class="buttonHighlight"></div>
            <a href="/contact" class="button"><h3>Contact Us</h3><p>phone and email</p></a>
        </li>
        <li id="about-button"><div class="buttonHighlight"></div>
            <a href="/about" class="button"><h3>About Us</h3><p>all about us</p></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

EDIT: The navbar was designed around www.panic.com/coda navbar. It works just fine on the iPad.
EDIT: The current setup works on all non-iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation relies on hover events to trigger menu content to appear.

A hover event is triggered by the mouse moving over an element.

Touch devices, such as all iOS devices, as well as most, if not all, contemporary smartphones and tablets, do not have a mouse and as such there is no way for a hover event to be triggered.

You cannot achieve what you want on contemporary touch devices using only CSS.

There are various touch-related events that can be fired and responded to using JavaScript. You will need to opt not for a CSS-based menu-triggering approach and instead use a JavaScript-based approach where both hover and touch events are handled to produce the menu system you desire.

Comment: The hove is just for the first menu, and I gave that a "#" so that it would stay open on touch devices. I used my roommates ASUS tablet to test the functionality and it worked just fine. It also works just fine on my mobile phone. (HTC Thunderbolt)